# How to put additional class within wordpress menu class list

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want a simple solution for the following code:

```
<li id="menu-item-11" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-11"><a class="nav-item-child nav-item-hover"href="#">Contact</a></li>
```

I want to put additional class "nav-item" within the class of "< li >" section keeping everything same so the code will show up as follows:

```
<li id="menu-item-11" class="nav-item menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-11"><a class="nav-item-child nav-item-hover"href="#">Contact</a></li>
```

Meaning the following class:

```
class="nmenu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-11"
```

Will be replaced by:

```
class="nav-item menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-11"
```

I want a valid way to put it into theme function.php file in order to implement it. I tried the following code:

```
function add_menuclassli($ulclass) {
   return preg_replace('/<ul /', '<li class="nav-item menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"', $ulclass);
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu','add_menuclassli');
```

But I am stuck on the last part "menu-item-11" - since the item number is unique and generates individually for each list. Please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just for one (or a few) menu item(s), you can do this in the **Appearance** > **Menus** admin page.

In Screen Options, in the upper right, make sure `CSS Classes` is checked, then you'll see this on the Menu Items:

[image: Admin Menu Showing CSS Classes field]

If you need to do this programatically, you can make use of the [`nav_menu_css_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_css_class/) filter. You should avoid using regular expressions for this kind of thing anways!

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'add_nav_item_class', 10, 4 );
function add_nav_item_class( $classes, $item, $args, $depth ){
    $classes[] = 'nav-item';

    return $classes;
}
```

Comment: Hello Xhynk, Thank you for the solution, really appreciate it. But I was thinking if it is possible to put the class through the php code/js code directly because I am trying to customize a theme where I do not want the users to put the class from the menu option on css section by their own, it should be a fixed class "nav-item" which should automatically added to < li > class. Thanks for you support.

Comment: Did you see the function I wrote? You stick it in your functions.php file and it will add it to every menu item `<li>` in your theme